# UITableView in each tab

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, sdk, tabs

I'm currently developing a tab bar based application with 5 tabs that have an UITableView each. Each tab is linked to a normal UIViewController, the first two with the ones that xCode creates by default and the others with the ones I created.
If I try to add a table view to the first two view controllers (default ones) everything works smoothly, but when I do the same with the others, the app crashes telling me that:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4e2f6f0'
```

and the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: in my .m file is this:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 2;
```

}

do you now any solution ? I've looked around with no result

thanks in advance for answers

Answer (score 0):

Check those two things.

1) if your other viewControllers are subclasses of UIViewController then they should implement the delegate methods:UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource. Meaning it is not only required to implement them in your code but to tell the compiler that you will.

```
@interface thirdViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

2) or try to see if your viewController is of type UITableViewController.

```
@interface thirdViewController : UITableViewController
```

Comment: I've tried to add the delegates but it keeps crashing and returning that error, I even tried and add a UITableViewController subclass and still, the problem persists.

Comment: Did you create a UITableView in your viewController initialized it and connected it to the IBOutlet in IB? The error basically means that you are passing nil where it expects uitableView.