# UIViewController in UITabBar based lifecycle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, lifecycle

I've set a UITabBr based app with many UIViewControllers for each tab that I added (5)
Now I've had problems with adding a TableView for each tab as i pointed here [UITableView in each tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5927661/uitableview-in-each-tab)
but nobody had a solution so I thought about it and tried many ways
the point now is: which method is called at first in the UIViewController when user touches a tab ? (viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear didn't work)

there is a specific lifecycle ?

here's the normal code, nothing is displayed in the console when you click on the tab

```
#

import "MusicView.h"


@implementation MusicView

@synthesize tv;



// Customize the number of sections in the table view.
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 10;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    //cell.textLabel.text = [elements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        NSLog(@"initWithNibName works");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad works");
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you set yourself as the datasource and delegate as well as subclassed UITableViewController and subscribed to the datasource and delegate protocols in your individual tab view controllers?

Comment: these are the steps I followed:

Comment: created an UIViewController (XIB+2 classes), linked it with a tab in the MainWindow.xib, then opened the controller just created, dragged in an UITableView, linked its datasource and delegate to the File Owner, added table view's methods in the .m and edited the .h with these two delegates UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate. Am I doing something wrong ? the app crashes in this occasion but the same thing in the views that scode gives you by default doesn't give problems. Do you know anything about its lifecycle ?

Comment: Why don't you just add two UITableViewController subclasses to your project instead of two UIViewControllers and add everything manually. From everything you said, you are still not subclassing UITableViewController in your .h files.

Comment: I need more controls in the same view but the app crashes giving me these errors -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3f460

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3f460'
*** Call stack at first throw:

Comment: Because UIViewController does not have that method. You need to use UITableViewController...

Comment: Are you calling this method anywhere in your code? The tableView should be the only thing calling the delegate methods. If you are reloading your data at any point in your code you should be using [tableview reloadData];

Answer (score 0):

`There is too much information you haven't provided.` We do not know what subclass it is from, and we do not know anything about the delegate / datasource methods.

Please follow this tutorial - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LBnPfAtswgw

Comment: I simply added an UIViewController to the project (XIB+2 classes) and assigned it to a tab of the UITabBar

Comment: a part from the table view, could you just give me infos about the lifecycle ? about the first method called thanks

Comment: What do you mean by LifeCycle ?

Comment: all the steps from the start of a class when called

Comment: in a comment down in this page I've described all the steps I went through

Comment: Please do not use the term LifeCycle. It's not appropriate for this project -) Well... please post you .h file.

Comment: Initialize an array for your tableview in the viewDidLoad method. Now in the cellForRowAtIndexPath, assign cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: I did it but it keeps giving me these errors -[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3f460

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4b3f460'
*** Call stack at first throw: